# Problema en servidor de correo

Tags: email, dns, gmail, cpanel

Actualmente tengo un VPS, con cuentas de CPanel para 3 dominios dentro del que tengo **abaco.edu.pe**, se realizó la solicitud a Google for Education para que nos otorguen algunas cuentas de correo electrónico gratuitas.

El problema es que, después de haber realizado las configuraciones de Entradas MX y seguido la guía de G Suite for Education para la configuración de correo electrónico en CPanel aún así tengo problemas con la recepción de correos (los correos de salida están OK).

Si envío un correo desde Outlook, Gmail o incluso una misma cuenta del dominio (abaco.edu.pe) me indica que no pudo ser entregado.

Haciendo seguimiento me resulta este error:

> The mail server could not deliver mail to xxxxxxxx@abaco.edu.pe. The account or domain may not exist, they may be blacklisted, or missing the proper dns entries.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Toolbox Check MX](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/) es una herramienta para para revisar el funcionamiento de los registros MX.

Para el dominio abaco.edu.pe indica que los registros DKIM y DMARC no están configurados, que falta el registro SPF válido y que no se encontraron intercambiadores de correo de Google. Para cada error se ofrece un enlace con detalles y el enlace al artículo de ayuda correspondiente.

Comment: Gracias muy amable, revisaré y pondré en marcha los detalles indicados, desconocía de esta herramienta.

Les pondré al tanto de como va.